# reusing Room or SQLite database in the app?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to figure out an android app that stores user's data in a database on sdcard.
But I don't know if it's possible to have these too:
even if the user deletes the app, the db remains and the user can access it.
So later they can re-install and give the app the path to the db file. The app uses that file as a database again.

Something like WhatsApp db, but the user must have the database as a file on their phone so they can transfer and store it anywhere. The data is large so it's not a good idea to get a backup file.

Is it possible to create it with Room or SQLite? and reuse it again?